# NodeJS API: Find a document into a collection by "Id" property , not by "_id" default in Mongodb

Tags: node.js, api, mongoose

I want to retrieve a document by property "id" in my schema, not use "_id" default of Mongodb.

I want to have response when I request like that:
https://sample-accounts-api.herokuapp.com/accounts/2

```
{
        attributes: {
          id: 2,
          user_id: 2,
          name: "Bカード",
          balance: 200
        }
      }
```

It's my Account Model:

```
var AccountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        id: {type: Number},
        user_id: {type: Number, ref: 'User'},
        name: String,
        balance: Number
});
```

And here is my Controller API:

```
const Account = require('../model/account');
exports.findOne = (req,res) => {
    Account
    .findById(???)
    .then(account => {
        if(!account) {
            return res.status(404).send({
                message: "Account not found with ID " 
            });
        }
        res.send(account);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        return res.status(505).send({
            message: "Something wrong retrieving account with Id "
        });
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    exports.findOne = (req,res) => {
    Account
    .findOne({'attributes.id':req.params.id})
    .then(account => {
        if(!account) {
            return res.status(404).send({
                message: "Account not found with ID " 
            });
        }
        res.send(account);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        return res.status(505).send({
            message: "Something wrong retrieving account with Id "
        });
    })
}
```

use `attributes.id` and map it against your `req.params.id`.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue.

My code:

```
const Account = require('../model/account');

exports.findOne = (req,res) => {
Account
// Find a Account by "id" property and except the "_id" & "__v" field
.findOne({id:req.param("id")}, {_id: 0, __v: 0}) 
.then(account => {
    if(!account) {
        return res.status(404).send({
            message: "Account not found with ID " 
        });
    }
    res.send({'attributes':account});
})
.catch(err => {
    return res.status(505).send({
        message: "Something wrong retrieving account with Id "
    });
})
```

}